# How to add geom_smooth() or stat_smooth() on geom_jitter() in GGPLOT

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following script:

```
require(datasets)
data(ToothGrowth)
library(ggplot2)
ToothGrowth$dose <- as.factor(ToothGrowth$dose)
p <- ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len, color=dose, shape=dose)) + 
  geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(0.2))+
  labs(title="Plot of length  by dose",x="Dose (mg)", y = "Length") +   stat_summary(fun.data=mean_sdl, size=0.6, geom="pointrange", color="black") 
p + theme_classic() +
    theme(axis.line.x = element_line(colour = 'black', size=0.5, linetype='solid'),
          axis.line.y = element_line(colour = 'black', size=0.5, linetype='solid'))
```

Which makes the figure like this:

[image]

My question is how can I add [smoothing line](http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/stat_smooth.html) for for the black (mean) points above?

I tried adding `stat_smooth()` but doesn't work.

Comment: The code isn't reproducible (and you've got >9,000 SO rep so you know what that means). Plus, a smoothing line for 3 points is nigh meaningless. What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: @hrbrmstr I made it reproducible for him

Answer (score 3):

You can do this directly via `geom_smooth` if you leave `dose` as numeric instead of making it a factor. For the color and shape mapping you can then either use `factor(dose)` or make a new categorical dose variable with a different name.

```
data(ToothGrowth)
# New categorical dose for shapes and colors
ToothGrowth$Dose <- factor(ToothGrowth$dose)

ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x = dose, y = len, color = Dose, shape = Dose)) + 
    geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(0.2))+
    labs(title="Plot of length  by dose",x="Dose (mg)", y = "Length") +   
    stat_summary(fun.data=mean_sdl, size=0.6, geom="pointrange", color="black")  + 
    theme_classic() +
    theme(axis.line.x = element_line(colour = 'black', size=0.5, linetype='solid'),
         axis.line.y = element_line(colour = 'black', size=0.5, linetype='solid')) +
    geom_smooth(aes(x = dose, y = len), inherit.aes = FALSE, se = FALSE)
```

[image]

If you really want your x axis to be categorical you need to draw the smoothed line through the integers each factor level represents by using `as.numeric` on the categorical dose variables.  This is drawing a smoothed line using the *ranks* of the x variable instead of the actual values, which may or may not make sense in your real situation.

```
ToothGrowth$Dose <- factor(ToothGrowth$dose)

ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x = Dose, y = len, color = Dose, shape = Dose)) + 
    geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(0.2))+
    labs(title="Plot of length  by dose",x="Dose (mg)", y = "Length") +   
    stat_summary(fun.data=mean_sdl, size=0.6, geom="pointrange", color="black")  + 
    theme_classic() +
    theme(axis.line.x = element_line(colour = 'black', size=0.5, linetype='solid'),
         axis.line.y = element_line(colour = 'black', size=0.5, linetype='solid')) +
    geom_smooth(aes(x = as.numeric(Dose), y = len), inherit.aes = FALSE, se = FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
require(datasets)
data(ToothGrowth)
library(ggplot2)
ToothGrowth$dose <- as.factor(ToothGrowth$dose)
p <- ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len, color=dose, shape=dose)) + 
  geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(0.2))+
  labs(title="Plot of length  by dose",x="Dose (mg)", y = "Length") +   stat_summary(fun.data=mean_sdl, size=0.6, geom="pointrange", color="black") 
p + theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.line.x = element_line(colour = 'black', size=0.5, linetype='solid'),
        axis.line.y = element_line(colour = 'black', size=0.5, linetype='solid'))

lo <- loess(as.numeric(dose)~len,data=ToothGrowth)

p1 <- p+geom_line(aes(x=predict(lo)))
```

[image]